# How attach real-time models to controllers in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, dashboard, pubnub

I'm triying to show several views/controllers with data that come from a real-time json (with pubnub) for a dashboard.

In the angular.js regular docs I see something like:

```
function CounterCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {'counter':1};
};
```

But what I want is have a list of datasources, then notify views with the changes of the data and render them.

So, I can have:

```
counter1:{'counter':1} => Rendered by view1 and view2
counter2:{'counter':5} => Rendered by view3
```

view4 have not data yet. Some minutes later it arrive

```
counter3:{'counter':8} => Rendered by view4
```

Then counter1 is updated

```
counter1:{'counter':2}
```

I create a controller by each view type, some 2 views can be the same controller BUT display different data:

```
view1 & view3 are UpDownCtrl
view2 is LineGraphCtrl
```

In the dashboard, I need to update the views, and change the behaviour according to the data (or lack of it, to show a empty state).

P.D: I'm open to do this in another js framework if is tailored to this kind of task...

Comment: create an angular `service` to share data between controllers

Comment: I read the docs, and I understand that is for provide common functions to the controllers. But I don't get how map models to several controllers, as stated in this question.

Comment: try this video  http://egghead.io/video/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using PubNub as well, and have started a very basic PubNub service in my AngularJS app.

The service (work in progress):

```
app.factory('pubnub', function($rootScope) {
    var pubnub = {
        lastMessage: '',
        messages: [],
        callback: function(message) {
            pubnub.lastMessage = message;
            pubnub.messages.unshift(message);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('pubnubMessageReceived', message); 
        },
        getLastMessage: function() {
            return pubnub.lastMessage;
        },
        getMessages: function() {
            return pubnub.messages;
        }
    }

    PUBNUB.subscribe({
        channel    : 'my_channel',
        restore    : false, 
        callback   : pubnub.callback,
    });

    return pubnub;
});
```

One of the (many) controllers:

```
var ProjectController = function($scope, pubnub) {

    $scope.$on('pubnubMessageReceived', function(event, message) {
        console.log("pubnub message received in project controller",message);
        if(message.target == "project") {
            // The message is for me!! Do something with it
            $scope.data = message.data;
        }
    });
}
```

So I have one service listening for PubNub messages and broadcasting them over $rootScope, and then it is simple to have any controller listen for those messages. Once you receive a message in your controller, modify your $scope and it will automatically update your view.